# how to query on a pipleline in mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb compass.
I am able to do so query a basic original data. But I want to do so after changing original data a bit. I can use a pipeline to do so. But how do I query on the results after obtained from pipeline.

Is there any way to save the results obtained after pipeline in mongodb compass to a new file/ data ?

I am building a search application where i need to query on 5 fields in order to retrieve the product.

There are five fields in my collection that I need to query for my application, three of them are strings and remaining two are list of strings. without indexing the query runs in 650ms. I am creating the text indexes on all five of fields (compound index) , the query optimiser in mongodb compass does not picks up this index for searching. The search type is of regex one. Also we cannot force it since it is of text type (regex). Lastly I created the sorted indexes on all fields individually, it works in about 1100 ms. I need it <500ms. Can anyone guide me on this ?

here is a bit of summary on it , I tried working with adding all text fields, the query selector does not uses them. I have tried adding them individually, as a text field, again the query selector does not uses them. Then I have tried adding them in regular manner (sorted), by adding all the fields individually, the query selector uses them, but the timing is about 1100 instead of 600. Also we cannot force the query to use the created index for execution , as from docs “You cannot use hint() if the query includes a $text query expression.”

Finally I tried adding a different field to search from. Advantage is that there is now only one field to look for. This reduces the time to about 350ms, which works in the scenario. But due to design issues I cannot push it into the actual deployment.

One of the final solutions will be to give user the option of choosing which fields to search from. So i am working with the java in backend. I need to create a kind of "contract" in the api method. So that we know which fields to search from apart from name field.

If someone can guide along how to create this kind of contract,

Thanking you.

Comment: Can you add your data, index details, query, execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/import-export/?_ga=2.86782815.615586477.1643336752-615757694.1643185160#procedure-1) this to export filtered data.

If you want to query further on pipeline data, you can either store that to another collection. Or you can apply few more pipeline stages.

Comment: Please add this in the question

Comment: done, added some other workarounds too.